How to measure brigthness and hue in Photoshop CS6?
Used "Curves" layer and color checker card (within the picture) to adjust black and white. Not really sure how to give reference RBG values of the card to the program.
Also, not sure how to measure brigthness of an individual pixel, since the Histogram just shows the RBG values of the selected points with color sample tool.


Change the color sample tool to HSB (hue,saturation, brightness)...
I would not use the color reference values of the chart; because they vary some, and because they are D50 values.


If you're going to be using a camera for scientific colorimetry you owe it to yourself to at least get an IT8 scanner calibration target (or other target) and the software to generate a color profile from it.  The color-perception rabbit hole is deep and many tools operate in an entirely subjective fashion that is going to produce inconsistent results if you don't get some control.  Getting your capture setup locked to one color temperature of light source and white balance, and then profiling it so you can convert your images into something standard like sRGB or a wider-gamut space if you need it should help you produce comparable results.
